# clean up pip by removing all unused packages and cache

Tags: python, pip

How do I remove **all the unused packages** in `pip`?

I'm aware of `pip-autoremove somepackage -y` for removing a specific package along with its dependencies but I'm looking to clean up all the unused orphan packages.

In `conda` there is `conda clean -a` command that is to remove unused packages and caches.

Comment: I'm pretty sure pip removes old versions of packages when upgrading, and finding out all the dependencies between every installed package is pretty complicated

Comment: Not aware of any, but you could probably write a shell script to loop through your `requirements.txt` and do a `git grep` on each one, then pipe it to `wc-l` to get a count of each time it's imported, then remove them as dependencies.

Comment: another good way to deal with what you are asking is making a new `venv` for each project, and then you won't have unused packages in your environment